# How can I run a function if there isn't a network connection in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, networking

I need a function to run (a `UIAlertView`) whenever there is a network connection error. I would like to do this as simply as possible. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this link [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) from Apple developer website.
Listen network changes and when it is notReachable show your alert view.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am writing in Swift 3. Is there a documentation for Swift? Thanks!

Comment: You can also Objective-C in Swift but if you want to use Swift sources just try this [Reachability for Swift](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift)

Comment: Thanks for the help!!!